# Disable user accounts after a certain time period

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

Is there a way to create a local user account on a Windows 7 Professional machine that stays active only for a certain length of time e.g 12 months?

The reason for doing this is we loan out laptops for 12 months to students, however some are less than prompt at bringing them back, if they were locked out of the laptop this would force them to bring the machine back in if they hoped to continue using the laptop.

Also a warning would be helpful, although I could do this with a scheduled task.

Comment: They could simply disable this once they learned of this.  Since your dealing with non-domain accounts this really isn't possible.

Comment: The accounts are limited user accounts. Surely there must be some software that can be run as an admin only that would accomplish this?

Comment: The only software I am aware of that deals with this, requires it to be a domain account, local users are not really designed in this manner.  My suggestion...start withholding their ability to register for classes if they don't return it.

Answer (score 1):

You can, as Admin, schedule this in a batch file:
Net User UserName /active:no

But this can be outmaneuvered pretty easily with HBCD...
You can either encrypt the HD, or put you OS in a VHD.

One more option, which I haven't tried, is the [Prey Project](http://preyproject.com/).